# Call WebService method created with Netbeans and Glassfish from browser(localhost)

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish, webservice-client

This may sound like a dumb question but i am new to web services.

I followed [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) and successfully created a Calculator web service up to the point where i created a local client application that consumed the web service method (A java class with main method which calls the web service method).

My question now is how can i access this method via my browser and set the parameters there, just get an XML/JSON result.

My guess is that i am missing something and i have to publish the web service somehow.

Any solutions, links are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have hosted your webservice on glassfish server. Now you want to consume it using internet browser like you did it using test webservice option in net beans.

That means you need to built your own client which runs on web browser.

You need to built a webpage having two input fields in it and a button as result and whenever you hit this button call your webservice and display it's result. You can follow any simple tutorial of web client or application and again you can deployed it on glassfish or apache server.

Also you can use soapui (a client to consume web services) to import your wsdl and access its methods, providing inputs and get result in form of soap.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What i would like to do is access the web service via the browser. Eg. http://localhost:8080/CalculatorWSApp/CalculatorWS/add?i=1&j=2 and the result to be an int 2.